# Sram Rival 11 speed + GX 10 speed dérailleur

Tags: sram, shifting, gravel

Do you know if I can use Sram Rival 11 speed shifyers with a GX 10 speed dérailleur and if it will shift properly?
I am planning to use an 11speed 11-42 cassette.
Of course à grave monster project 
I already have the derailleur, that's why I ask...
If it does not work I will buy a Rival derailleur.

Answer (score 1):

SRAM road and mountain 10 speed and road 11 speed rear derailleurs share the same actuation ratio--the amount of derailleur movement per mm of cable pulled by the shifter.  SRAM labels this system "Exact Actuation" and it is used on both 10s mountain and 10 & 11 speed road shifters and derailleurs.  Also to note is that since you'll be using an 11 speed cassette with an 11 speed shifter, there's no cog spacing incompatibility.  Some SRAM fans want the hydraulic shifter that 11 speed systems offer, but want to keep the 10 speed rear end, cassette and derailleur.  This will not work well because the 11 speed shifter is pulling cable to make the 11 speed inter-cog gap. The derailleur responds correctly, moving as if in an 11 speed system, but the cog spacing of the 10s cassette is wider and the result is poor shifting.

At any rate, I digress.  Your plan should result in normal shifting.  One gotcha might be the GX derailleur being able to handle the wide range 11-42 cassette.  I believe the spec'd max large cog is 36t for a GX rear der. If the 42t cog is way out of the GX's max low cog spec, or if the total capacity spec is grossly exceeded, other problems may be faced.  Also the GX derailleur has no barrel adjuster, so you'll need an inline adjuster to manipulate cable tension.

The great Lennard Zinn [discusses mixing SRAM road 10 and 11 speed drivetrain components](https://www.velonews.com/gear/technical-faq-make-11-speed-shifters-work-with-10-speed/) in this Q & A article at velonews.com.

Comment: Thanks for the barrel adjuster suggestion. I have done that before but did not think about it this time.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to have good shifting (very much needed).

Comment: Yes I just want to go on hydraulic shifting, try Sram, since on the other bike I have Shimano hydro. And since I have a GX 10 speed dérailleur all should be good. I had it before on my MTB with a 1x system with a max 42 cog, it should work, let's see. Worst case scenario I will add one of these derailleur extender.

Comment: You're welcome. It's apparently a pretty common CX and gravel arrangement you're putting together and works well. Happy riding.

Comment: Perfect for confirming my researches, I appreciate it guys, thanks Jeff 